# How to write summary formula to calculate percentage based on coloums total?

Tags: dashboard, custom-reports, reports-api, joined-reports, summary

I did some research but i am unable to get it.
[image]

I want  to create a formula for this calculation:
Total Records- Total CompletedOnboarding/Total Records *100.

Please guide

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386586&type=1 Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding , i tried this before posting this question it doesn't return the exact percentag which which should be around 93 gives me 100 percent